# Template var in gruntfile doesn't always work

Tags: gruntjs

In my gruntfile I noticed that I can't always get a template variable to work. Below is a very simple small grunt file to show the issue. The `copy` task will understand `<%= yeoman.app %>`, but the `less` task does not.

I suppose this has something to do with the `files` syntax, but I dont understand why. Can someone elaborate? And.. how can I get `less` to work?

```js
'use strict';

module.exports = function (grunt) {
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

  var yeomanConfig = {
    app: 'app',
    dist: 'dist'
  };

  grunt.initConfig({
    yeoman: yeomanConfig,

    copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: '404.html'
        }]
      }
    },

    less: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/main.less']
        }
      }
    }
  });
};
```

`grunt copy`: works

`grunt less`: Warning: An error occurred while processing a template (_ is not defined). Use --force to continue.

note, I'm using grunt 0.4.2 and node 0.10.13